# Avatar animation sync issue in NAF (Network a-frame)

Tags: aframe

I have avatar with animations, like flying, floating, eyes, etc. and perform specific animation based on keycode mapping with specific animation.

to perform specific animation on specific key, i have created custom animation component as follow schema:

```
schema: {
           keyCode: { default: stopAllAnimation }
        }
```

and put that element and component in network schema:

```
{
   selector: ".AvatarRoot",
   component: "own-animation"
}
```

Locally/Individually it is working fine but in NAF I am facing the syncing issue like play specific animation not sync in other tab/screen.

Any one know how avatar animation works in network a-frame? and cloud be possible to sync perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make things with a-frame schema and register component with a-frame extras included to make animation from gtlf/glb models.

The flow is like you need to set the register component with clip name in local JS file like this

```
let currentKeyDown = null;
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {            
     currentKeyDown = e.which;
     const avatar = document.querySelector("#local-avatar");
     switch (currentKeyDown) {
        case 37: // left arrow key
           avatar.setAttribute("player-info", "clip:Walk");
           break;               
        }
      });
```

and in register component if previous clip and new clip are different set a new clip. like this

```
if (oldData.clip !== this.data.clip) {
              this.character.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {clip: this.data.clip, crossFadeDuration: 1});
            }
```

Maybe you can take this code for reference and I have added to glitch. [Glitch walking demo](https://www.glitch.com/edit/#!/glorious-invited-yarn)